# Experience Editor's unexpected behavior

Tags: personalization, xconnect

I have the below situation.

I have a .NET Core application that sends a Contact with Facet data to xConnect to show interest in a category (using profile keys).

A Sitecore website, on which I track a Contact, to show a commercial based on interest shown in the category.

It worked first time when I tried, i got the commercial that i was expecting. Than i updated my profile keys again in my .NET Core application, and i can see my `ContactBehaviourProfile` being updated to the new interest.

However, when i log into the Sitecore website and start tracking the Contact with changed interests, the commercial from the first setting poped up.

I have my rules set up like this:
[image: Rules]

I don't have much experience with Sitecore but heard somewhere that Contact data is flushed to xDB when session ends,

Does Sitecore 9/ xConnect have the same behaviour?

EDIT:
I tried updating and using the RemoveFromSession method. I am now calling the method before returning the view but i am still getting the old Contact.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Track(string email)
    {
        if (Request.Form["Email"] != null)
        {
            if (Request.Form["Email"] != "")
                Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("email", Request.Form["email"]);
        }
        var contact = Tracker.Current.Session.Contact; // this is for debugging
        Sitecore.XConnect.Contact Contact = GetContactWithBehaviourProfile(email); // this is for debugging
        FillViewBag();
        var manager = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager;
        manager.RemoveFromSession(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Could u upgrade to v9 update 1 and release the contact so that any facets get reloaded on next request without you needing tok update the trackers contact manually?

Comment: I was going to try that but i have little experience with updating Sitecore or with Sitecore at all for that matter so i'm a little hesitant.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to update the ContactBehavior Profile on the Tracker.

Comment: You are my hero

Comment: I have tried updating to Sitecore v9 update 1 and added the code to remove the Contact from session, however this has not solved my issue. After restarting my server the Contact in the Tracker is updated but the manager.RemoveFromSession() method does not seem to work

Comment: When you refresh, did it work?  It's supposed to get the Contact back on the NEXT request.

Comment: Nope i've even tried opening the page in a new browser

Comment: Hmmm...is it possible the condition is not exactly what you wanted? That condition above will still apply since the values for the "Transport" profile will still be in system.  Those values add up and remain in the system to identify the pattern card match.

Comment: I dont think its the condition, when i restart the server it does give me the updated contact

Comment: What I meant is that the Transport rule you have above will still apply even if you update the contact's data.  Btw, I haven't checked yet but it's possible that since it's an aggregated data, which could mean that data comes from the reporting server, it may just take a bit of time for that specific condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SC 9 is flushed immediately unlike previous versions. With your particular issue, my guess is that you didn't update the Tracker's Contact (assuming that you are doing this on the same tracker session). This means that updating the xConnect Contact does not automatically update the Tracker's Contact.  This is mainly true on v. 9 Initial Release.  So, you must update your Tracker's Contact also when updating xConnect's Contact.  However, in v9 Update 1, Sitecore has provided a new `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager` method :

`manager.RemoveFromSession(Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId); // Use tracker ID, not xConnect ID`

to allow the contact to be reloaded in next request.  [Find out more here.](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-contacts/contact-facets/update-facets.html)

**UPDATE**

Here's how to access the `ContactBehaviorProfile` facet as [shown in the Sitecore Docs](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/tracking-and-session/tracker/tracking-contacts/contact-facets/access-facets-in-session.html). At this point, you should just be able to update the data but of course it depends how much data you need to update, it may get a bit more complex.

> var xConnectFacets = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact.GetFacet("XConnectFacets");
>
> ContactBehaviorProfile cbp = xConnectFacets.Facets[ContactBehaviorProfile.DefaultFacetKey] as ContactBehaviorProfile;

Comment: I fill the Facets from a .NET Core application so i don't think this is the issue, i will be taking a look at the ContactManager tho

Comment: I haven't tested it yet because i'm not done updating but RemoveFromSession seems to be the solution

Comment: I'm getting the following error :'TFacet' does not contain a definition for 'Facets' and no extension method 'Facets' accepting a first argument of type 'TFacet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
i believe it wants me to specify the specific Facet, i tried ContactBehaviorProfile and IContactBehaviorProfiles. neither worked

Comment: Turns out i was missing the Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.dll`and i had to specifiy IXConnectFacets between brackets with the GetFacet method

Comment: One more problem, the ContactBehaviorProfile is saved in a Facet but is also a property of Contact called BehaviorProfiles, i believe the property is actually used by sitecore because updating the Facet in memory did not do anything. I tried editing the property but i can't seem to figure out how to convert the xConnect ContactBehaviorProfile to the BehaviorProfiles property

Comment: You may want to post that as a separate question and hopefully someone can help out.  I won't be available for a bit just in case you need an answer immediately.  I'm glad you're moving along though.